# [CMAKE]: Can't remove the .d and .gcno files generated by cmake using make clean command

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am building my project with cmake. I am able to generate the Makefiles on linux platform and hence able to build the project as well.

However, When I want to clean the all generated files, I am not able to do so.
I am not able to remove the `foo.c.gcno` and `foo.c.d` kind of files, using `make clean` command.

Is there any specific command in cmake to remove these intermediate files ?

Note: I have different directories for Cmake-source and build. I am concerned about the generated files(*.c.gcno and *.d) in the build directory. Rest all other files like *.o and *.so are cleaned up by make clean command.

Comment: Not sure about `.gcno` files, but `.d` files contains dependencies, and they should correctly processed by CMake (that is, being deleted on `make clean`). Show your project (in form of [mcve]).

Comment: More info needed, for example: what do you mean you can't remove them? - do you mean `make clean` does not remove them or do you mean it fails to remove them due to some reason (like permissions)? what error (if any do you get)? It might be that you just need to add the file types to the cleanup list. We need a lot more info as @Tsyvarev mentioned example code is always useful : ) **Note**: `.gcno` files are generated by gnu coverage (gcov) compile option (incase others are wandering).

Comment: Yes 'make clean'  is not removing those(*.gcno and *.d) files. I am not getting any error on doing make clean but these files are not removed however these were generated during building the files. 
Anyway I think solution is adding custom target distclean in CMakeLists.txt .
https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2003-June/003953.html

Answer (score 0):

In CMake, you cannot generate a `Makefile` and delete the rest. All the generated files, and an installed CMake, is still needed to build the project.

You should have run `cmake <source directory>` in a different directory in the first place. Let's call it build directory.

Then, build directory can be completely removed without changing the source code.